# How can I create a function with custom parameters

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, angular, vue.js

I can't express this better so I'll try as much as I can. Here I wrote a function that will create an element in the html #root div

This is the function that I wrote

```js
var root = document.getElementById("root");

function createEl(element, selectorType, selectorName, src, input) {
    var newEl = document.createElement(element);

    if (selectorType == "id") {
        newEl.id = selectorName;
    };
    
    if (selectorType == "class") {
        newEl.classList.add(selectorName);
    };

    newEl.src = src;
    newEl.innerHTML = input;
    root.appendChild(newEl);
};
```

Now instead of doing it like this:

```js
createEl (
       "div",
       "id",
       "newId",
       null,
       "Hello World"
)
```

I want to do it like this

```js
createEl (
       el: "div",
       s: "id",
       sName: "newId",
       src: null,
       in: "Hello World"
)
```

I don't know if this will make sense cuz I didn't know how to express it in another way. :(

Comment: pass an object and add custom params in that object

Comment: how can i do that, im sorry.

Comment: You need to wrap those parameters in curly braces to turn them into an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). Next you write your function as `function createEl(params) { ... }` and inside it, you can now refer to `params.el`, `params.s`, etc.

Comment: You're looking for this I guess: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/a685Lcnt/

Comment: Yup but @aRvi answered my question already :)

Comment: Sure, I'm not here for rep :)

Comment: You're a good and wholesome person :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing custom params

```
var root = document.getElementById("root");


function createEl({element, selectorType, selectorName, src, input, parentTag}) {

    var newEl = document.createElement(element);

    if (selectorType == "id") {
        newEl.id = selectorName;
    };
    
    if (selectorType == "class") {
        newEl.classList.add(selectorName);
    };

    newEl.src = src;
    newEl.innerHTML = input;
    parentTag.appendChild(newEl);
};

var inputParams = {
    element: "div", 
    selectorType: "id", 
    selectorName: "newId",
    src: null, 
    input: "Hello World",
    parentTag: root
}
createEl(inputParams)
```

Comment: but what if I want to specifiy the params when I create an element. Like I dont want to create elements with the same tags and other params as the last one

Comment: you can pass that tags in the params as well

Comment: Like this? ```
element: element, 
    selectorType: selectorType, 
    selectorName: selectorName,
    src: src, 
    input: input```

Comment: I get this error in my console. ```Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined
    at createEl (script.js:17)
    at script.js:40```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an object to the function. Also rename `in` since `in` is a reserve keyword in javascript

```
var root = document.getElementById("root");

function createEl(b) {
  b = b.src;
  var a = document.createElement(element);
  "id" === selectorType && (a.id = selectorName);
  "class" === selectorType && a.classList.add(selectorName);
  a.src = b;
  a.innerHTML = input;
  root.appendChild(a);
}
var obj = {
  el: "div",
  s: "id",
  sName: "newId",
  src: null,
  inp: "Hello World"
};
```

Comment: but what if I want to specifiy the params when I create an element. Like I dont want to create elements with the same tags and other params as the last one. How may I do that?

Answer (score 0):

To be safe use interface

```
interface ElementParam {
    element: string, 
    selectorType: string, 
    selectorName: string,
    src: string,
    input: string,
    parentTag: string
}

function createEl(type: ElementParam) {
   .....
};
```